# RSA verification time

Tags: rsa, digital-signature

How many clock cycles does RSA1024 with exponent of 65537 need to verify a message ?
Sure Times will be different according to processor, that's why I asked for number of clock cycles

Comment: I found this and it was very helpful, https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html) website that contains benchmarks for all cryptographic hashes

Answer (score 2):

Run `openssl speed rsa` to have some idea on the speed on different machines.

Number of clock cycles will differ from one machine to another, even if you discount software differences.

Verification is performed using a public key; if the public exponent is small, verification will be fast. If the public exponent is large it may take much longer.

Some CPU's even have a Montgomery multiplier (e.g. the Sun Niagara based processors) to speed up RSA operations.

In other words: it depends.

Comment: For this processor (amd64; IB+AES (306a9); 2012 Intel Core i5-3210M; 2 x 2500MHz) or any other processor

How can I calculate the time needed for RSA verification ?


How can I use these tables if they may help ? http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html

Comment: @ahammadz Something suddenly missing from my answer, ahammadz? Why did you remove the accept?